# Sending variable in mail view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am currently working on my project in which I want to send variable to my mail view. I have tried many a times but it gives me error. Kindly tell me what I am doing wrong

Code of my Controller

```
$data = array('to'=> $patientEmail, 'from'=>'nida.office123@gmail.com', 'sender_name'=>'Admin', 'receiver_name'=>$request->name, 'subject'=>'Appointment Cancellled', 'message'=> $request->cancelMessage);
Mail::Send(['html'=>"mail/cancelAppointmentmail"], $data, function($message) use ($data) {
    $message->to($data['to'], $data['receiver_name'])->subject($data['subject']);
    $message->from($data['from'], $data['sender_name']);
});
```

Code of my view

```
<p> <?php echo $data['message']; ?></p>
```

Comment: It should be `<p> <?php echo $message  ?></p>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Blade syntax in your view:

```
<p>{{ $message }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the `Mail::send` method are variables that you can use in the view. The key of the value is the name of the variable in the view:

Your array

```
$data = array(
    'to'=> $patientEmail,
    'from'=>'nida.office123@gmail.com',
    'sender_name'=>'Admin',
    'receiver_name'=>$request->name,
    'subject'=>'Appointment Cancellled',
    'message'=> $request->cancelMessage
);
```

will result in the view having access to the following variables:

```
$to = $patientEmail;
$from = 'nida.office123@gmail.com';
$sender_name = 'Admin';
$receiver_name = $request->name;
$subject ='Appointment Cancellled';
$message = $request->cancelMessage;
```

So where you wrote

```
<p><?php echo $data['message']; ?></p>
```

You should write

```
<p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
```

Or with Blade syntax:

```
<p>{{ $message }}</p>
```

I know I'm late to the party, but as others failed to mention the cause of your problem, I wanted to write my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p>{{ $message }}</p>
```

If you have html input then:

```
<p>{!! $message !!}</p>
```